# Why is my string variable not concatenating in my Powershell function?

Tags: function, powershell, event-log

I'm writing a function to Write-EventLog with the information changing depending on arguments. One of those arguments is the message, but it will not display in the actual event log. Only the string portion that's hard coded.

I've tried assigning it to a variable and outputting it to make sure it's there and it shows that even though the variable type is string it won't concatenate in the function.

```
$testmsg1 = "The script successfully completed an operation"

Function Log-This($level, $message){

    If ($level -eq "Information"){
        $testmsg1
        $msg = "INFO: $message" 
        $msg
        Write-EventLog -LogName Application `
            -EventId 1099 `
            -EntryType Information `
            -Message $msg `
            -Source "Windows Error Reporting"
        }
... 
}
$testmsg1.GetType()

Log-This "Information", $testmsg1
```

This produces:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                        
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                        
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                                                                                   
The script successfully completed an operation
INFO:
```

What I'm going for is the string "INFO: The script successfully completed an operation". What am I doing wrong to not have the string concatenate?

Comment: Don't use the brackets in the function call. Just write `Log-This "Information" $testmsg1`

Comment: @Theo Thanks for pointing that out. It doesn't change the results or behavior but I'll make those changes.

Comment: @datagreenhorn please update your question accordingly!

Comment: @tituszban Hi Titus. My question is why the arguments being passed to this function are not being recognized when I go to concatenate them into the message variable.

Comment: Don't use a comma in the function call either.

Comment: @js2010 
Thanks man, that helped. It had nothing to do with the parenthesis. Just the comma.

Answer (score 1):

When evoking the function you need to identify the parameters for it individually.

e.g.

```
Log-This -level "Information" -message $testmsg1
```

Thanks @js2010 for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a comma in the function call either.